# Incorrect output when processing batch of inputs from file (converting pre-to-postfix)

Tags: python

I am having trouble writing my results into my output file. I'm trying to recursively convert from prefix to postfix. If I copy the input all at once separately, the output overwrites it. If there is a way that I could print a block of input followed by a block of output that would also work.

```
import sys


def isoperator(i):  # check if the input is an operator
    if i in ['$', '^', '*', '/', '+', '-']:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def isoperandoroperator(i):  # check if the input is an operand
    if i.isalpha and i.isnumeric or isoperator(i):
        return True
    else:
        return False

my_list = sys.argv[1]
my_output = sys.argv[2]


def recursivepretopost(input):  # method to convert from pre to postfix, takes input file as argument
    char = input.read(1)
    if char == '\n':
        return ''
    if char == ' ':
        return ''
    if isoperator(char):   # if the character is an operator, perform recursive call to check the next character
        return recursivepretopost(input) + recursivepretopost(input) + char
    else:  # if the character is an operand, return the operand
        return char


with open(my_list, 'r') as file, open(my_output, 'w') as i:  # use file to refer to the file object and open output file
    for d in file:
        i.write('Input: ' + d)
        i.write('Output: ')
        i.write(recursivepretopost(file) + '\n')
```

Here is the input of prefix expressions:

```
-+ABC
-A+BC
$+-ABC+D-EF
-*A$B+C-DE*EF
**A+BC+C-BA
/A+BC +C*BA  
*-*-ABC+BA  
/+/A-BC-BA  
*$A+BC+C-BA 
//A+B0-C+BA
*$A^BC+C-BA
```

This is my output:

```
Input: -+ABC
Output: ABC+-
Input: 
Output: AB-C+DEF-+$
Input: 
Output: ABCDE-+$*EF*-
Input: 
Output: ABC+*CBA-+*
Input: 
Output: ABC+/
Input:  +C*BA  
Output: AB-C*BA+-*
Input:  
Output: ABC-/BA-+/
Input:  
Output: ABC+$CBA-+*
Input:  
Output: AB0+/CBA+-/
Input: 
Output: ABC^$CBA-+*
```

But this is the intended output:

```
Input: -+ABC
Output: AB+C-
Input: -A+BC
Output: ABC+-
Input: $+-ABC+D-EF
Output: $+-ABC+D-EF
Input: -*A$B+C-DE*EF
Output: ABCDE-+$*EF*-
Input: **A+BC+C-BA
Output: ABC+*CBA-+*
Input: /A+BC +C*BA
Output: ABC+/
Input: *-*-ABC+BA
Output: AB-C*BA+-*
Input: /+/A-BC-BA
Output: ABC-/BA-+/
Input: *$A+BC+C-BA
Output: ABC+$CBA-+*
Input: //A+B0-C+BA
Output: AB0+/CBA+-/
Input: *$A^BC+C-BA
Output: ABC^$CBA-+*
```

Comment: `input` is a python built-in, use something else as your parameter names.

Comment: What is the point of `isoperandoroperator(i)`, this function is never called and if `i` is a `str`, both `i.isalpha` and `i.isnumeric` are functions so you must actually call them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't in how you're writing to your output file, it's in how you're reading from your input file. Your `for` loop iterates through the open file, line by line. You then *also* call that file's `read` method, which advances the current position in the file, which screws up your loop. This is essentially the same problem as the classic "Don't remove items from a list while you're iterating through it" gotcha.

The simplest way to fix your existing recursive function would be to create a [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) instance of each string you wish to process. A StringIO supports reading as if it were a file, even though it's simply a string stored in memory.

Other things I changed:

- Gave variables more descriptive names, and put function names in snake_case
- Changed function comments to docstrings
- Stripped each line of left and right whitespace, including `\n`, and removed spaces, so that you don't need to handle those within your function
- Simplified how `is_operator` returns its boolean, and checked membership in a set rather than a list
- Removed unused `isoperandoroperator`
- Used [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for formatting output

```
from io import StringIO
import sys


def is_operator(char):
    """Check if the input is an operator."""
    return char in {'$', '^', '*', '/', '+', '-'}

def recursive_pre_to_post(stream):
    """Convert from pre to postfix.
    Takes input file or string buffer as argument
    """
    char = stream.read(1)
    if is_operator(char):
        # If the character is an operator, perform recursive call to
        # check the next character.
        return (recursive_pre_to_post(stream) +
                recursive_pre_to_post(stream) + 
                char)
    else:
        # If the character is an operand, return the operand.
        return char


in_name = sys.argv[1]
out_name = sys.argv[2]

with open(in_name) as in_file, open(out_name, 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        line = line.strip().replace(' ', '')
        out_file.write(f'Input: {line}\n')
        result = recursive_pre_to_post(StringIO(line))
        out_file.write(f'Output: {result}\n')
```